# Unable to create Channel from class io.netty.channel.sctp.nio.NioSctpChannel

Tags: java, netty

```
**chatclient.java**
 package com.examplechat;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap;
import io.netty.channel.Channel;
import io.netty.channel.EventLoopGroup;
import io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup;
import io.netty.channel.sctp.nio.NioSctpChannel;
public class ChatClient {   
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, IOException  {
      new ChatClient("localhost", 8000).run();
    }   
    private final String host;
    private final int port;

    public ChatClient(String host, int port) {
        super();
        this.host = host;
        this.port = port;
    }
    public void run() throws InterruptedException, IOException {
  EventLoopGroup group = new NioEventLoopGroup();  
  try {
      Bootstrap bootstrap = new Bootstrap()
              .group(group)
              .channel(NioSctpChannel.class)
              .handler(new ChatClientInitilizer());       
      Channel channel = bootstrap.connect(host, port).sync().channel(); 
      BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
     while(true) {
         channel.write(in.readLine()+ "\r\n");
          }     
    }
  finally {
    group.shutdownGracefully();  } 
  } 
    }
**ChatServer.java**
package com.examplechat;
import io.netty.bootstrap.ServerBootstrap;
import io.netty.channel.EventLoopGroup;
import io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup;
import io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketChannel;
public class ChatServer {
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException  {
        new ChatServer(8000).run();
    }
    private final int port;
    public ChatServer(int port) {
        super();
        this.port = port;
    }
    public void run() throws InterruptedException  {
        EventLoopGroup bossGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
        EventLoopGroup workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
        try {
            ServerBootstrap bootstrap = new ServerBootstrap()
            .group(bossGroup, workerGroup)
            .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
            .childHandler(new ChatServerInitializer());
        bootstrap.bind(port).sync().channel().closeFuture().sync();
        }
        finally {
            bossGroup.shutdownGracefully();
            workerGroup.shutdownGracefully();
        }       
    }}
```

> I'm trying to create a chat Application using netty. When I try to run the chat client once I initiate chatserver java application. It shows

- Exception in thread "main" io.netty.channel.ChannelException: Unable
  to create Channel from class class
  io.netty.channel.sctp.nio.NioSctpChannel at
  io.netty.channel.ReflectiveChannelFactory.newChannel
  (ReflectiveChannelFactory.java:40)

I've even changed the dependencies at pom.xml still i'm receiving the same error every time I run it

> **Update** 
>    ***Error-1:*** `Unable to create Channel error` has been cleared by myself

I've answered it myself please help me fix this second issue

> ***Error-2*:** I'm getting a new error called **WARNING**: `Failed to initialize a channel. Closing: [id: 0x9e4e05e0] java.lang.ClassCastException: io.netty.channel.sctp.nio.NioSctpChannel cannot be cast to io.netty.channel.socket.SocketChannel`

Here's the github link if you need https://github.com/cyborgsri/Chat-Application/tree/master/netty-chat-youtube/src/main/java/com/examplechat.

Comment: Also please let me know If you want me to include the other files too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error happens because you use:

```
public class ChatServerInitializer extends ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>
```

Change it to:

```
public class ChatServerInitializer extends ChannelInitializer<Channel>
```

Comment: Great! Thank you so much, Norman. It works now even with <SocketChannel>. I tried to cast the `NioSocketCannel` Instead of `NioServerSocketChannel` in the ChatServer Class.

Comment: I'm trying to learn about this tracking project, In your example ChatServer app, we have used **`messageReceived`** function to display the output on console but in the link below they have used `MainEventHandler.Java` to receive data from the pipelines of each protocol But they are storing only the `positionID` in the database. I'm not sure how the other details are saved, could you help me with this?
 [https://github.com/tananaev/traccar/tree/master/src/org/traccar]

Answer (score 1):

I was getting error as

> `Unable to create Channel from class class io.netty.channel` ***which
>   is*** *Caused by*: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException:
>   ibsctp.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or
>   directory`

This error was cleared once I install lksctp-tools by:

> `sudo apt-get install lksctp-tools`

Now channel has been registered. But I'm getting a new error that 
**WARNING:**

> `Failed to initialize a channel. Closing: [id: 0x9e4e05e0]
>   java.lang.ClassCastException: io.netty.channel.sctp.nio.NioSctpChannel
>   cannot be cast to io.netty.channel.socket.SocketChannel`